# What is the use of the ampersand in regular expressions in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Guys I have this regular expression in Perl which I don't understand.

```
s/\w+$/($`!)$&/;
```

The original string was

```
"huge dinosaur"
```

After that regular expression is executed, the string is now:

```
"huge (huge !)dinosaur"
```

I quite dont understand how that happened. And I don't understand what the ampersand is doing there. I understand the $`, but why is it that it's there, from what i know the $` takes the value before the match, which is i think nothing because there is no matching expression before the that regular expression above.

If somebody can link me to some very helpful tutorial on regular expressions on Perl is really appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I understand now what the ampersand means, it saves the match and the $` saves the value before the match, Now what i dont understand again is this whole part:

```
($`!)$&
```

how did this part became

```
(huge !)
```

Comment: Google `perlvar` and then do a find for `$&`.  That is a rough start.

Comment: The bit in the second part of the s/// is just a double quoted string.

Comment: @squiguy There is (really) only one (semi-)"official" url for this http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%26

Comment: @BradGilbert I'm not as skilled in web links as you are :).  I tried to do that.

Comment: @squiguy I just right-click on the element and select "Inspect Element" (on Chrome) and add that to the link. Although if you knew the hex codes for `$` (24) and `&` (26) you could just url-escape them. (only works on perlvar page)

Comment: @BradGilbert Well thanks for the tip.  A lot of people don't respond to comments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're correct, `` $` `` is a  special variable which holds the contents before
the match. `$&` is similar, but holds what was matched and `$'` holds what was
after the match.

In `"huge dinosaur"`, `/\w+$/` matches  `dinosaur`. So the  variable contents
are:

```
$` => "huge "
$& => "dinosaur"
$' => ""
```

Note that what  was matched is `dinosaur`. Then it's  replacing the `dinosaur`
portion of  the string with  an opening  parens, `"huge "`,  exclamation mark,
closing parens and finally `dinosaur` (what was matched).

Check the Perl documentation for `perlvar` and `perlre`.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but I was alarmed to see that `$\`` does not end with TWO spaces. Is this a mistake or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @StevenLu my mistake, typed the space twice in the original phrase, sorry! And thanks for noticing

Answer (score 17):

`$&` (dollar ampersand) holds the entire regex match.

`$'` (dollar followed by an apostrophe or single quote) holds the part of the string after (to the right of) the regex match.

`` $` `` (dollar backtick) holds the part of the string before (to the left of) the regex match.

For more info, please consult http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html

Comment: I figured out how to include a backtick in a codespan and took the liberty to edit your answer, I hope you don't mind. You've got to start and end the codespan with double backticks, and leave a space before the closing one to separate the backtick of the character from the closing ones… confusing!

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how to do that.  Thanks!